# Scenekit scene takes too long to be displayed on the view

Tags: ios, swift, rendering, scenekit, sceneview

I need to show a 3D model on a SceneView in my iOS app, after its relative path (String) has been loaded from Firebase and passed to my **SCNScene(named: path)**.

The function that reads the path runs very quickly, but once I try to attach the scene to my SceneView, it takes pretty long before it can actually be displayed (5-6 sec).
The .scn file I'm trying to show is about **20MB**, and if I set **showStatistics = true**, it says my scene contains more than **200K triangles**.

I need a help in order to understand how I could strongly reduce the "loading" time of the scene.
I've already tried **reducing the number of polygons** and also using the SceneView method [prepare(_:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523375-prepare) in order to render my scene on a background thread and (ideally) speed up the process to display it, but nothing worked for me.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!